# Postfix: dynamically rewrite server name depended on senders domain

Tags: postfix

Im setting up postfix SMTP relay, that will be placed right after Exchange server.

Details:
1) postfix server name mail.server.com
2) we have several domains: a-domain.com, b-domain.com and etc..

I need to rewrite somehow emails headers. So recipient will not receive email like:

Received: from mail.server.com ([XX.XX.XX.X])

But will receive it from mail.a-domain.com ([XX.XX.XX.X]) if sender is user@a-domain.com
OR
from mail.b-domain.com ([XX.XX.XX.X]) if sender is user@b-domain.com

is this possible anyhow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postfix does not support directly this feature, but you can fiddle with transport maps in order to achieve your goal.

You can add many transports in `master.cf`, each for every domain, with a `-o` directive that adds a remap rule

In the `transport` file you set up the transport rule to use the transports specified in `master.cf` accordinf to the domain name

[This blog post](http://www.108.bz/posts/it/conditional-address-rewriting-with-postfix/) contains some examples and some links.

Comment: Thank you. Seems this is what i need exactly. I'll just create bunch of email gateways (for each domain) and strip the headers

Comment: finally I found this link http://tekman.livejournal.com/83609.html `sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_dependent_relayhost` works for me (as on my testing)